# Spring security application calling event listner

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I just create a listener by implementing `ApplicationListener`. 
Code is below:

```
public class SessionCreationEventListener  implements ApplicationListener{

    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionCreationEvent appEvent) {
        SessionCreationEvent event = (SessionCreationEvent) appEvent;
        //Object obj = null;
        //UserInfo userInfo = null;
        event.getSource();  
    }
}
```

But, not able to call this listen. where did I wrong in calling listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this Listener in web.xml file

```html
 <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

In a simple application the solution would be to add a HttpSessionListener.
Accordingly in my web.xml:

```html
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.web.SessionCounter</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The code for the listener would be :

```html
public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Total sessions created " + counter);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Now whenever Spring creates a session, my listener is activated and the message will be logged to the console. 
Total sessions created 1
The limitation with this approach is that the above listener is outside the Spring environment. If we need to access beans here, then the code gets complicated.
Spring Security provides a workaround for the problem. They have implemented a listener - HttpSessionEventPublisher.

```html
public class HttpSessionEventPublisher implements HttpSessionListener {
...
}
```

Comment: I have to add this in web.xml file or in spring's xml file.

Comment: That's the reason, My listener is not getting called. Thanx a lot.